# Bootstrap vertically align cols in one row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one row with two cols

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-1">
                Аты
                Имя
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-11">
                name
              </div>
</div>
```

I want to `name` string located on center of first `col`

How to make second `col` element vertically aligned to first `col`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To align the *content* of the columns, they first need to be the same height.

There are two basic CSS methods (that don't involve fixed values) for equalising heights.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/RaJarL)

**CSS Tables**

```css
.row div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.table {
  display: table;
}
.table div {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row table">
    <div class="col-xs-1 ">
      Аты Имя
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">
      name
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Flexbox**

```css
.row div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-xs-1 ">
      Аты Имя
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">
      name
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```